# to display only weekdays weekdays

Tags: javascript

I have a input date picker which will pick the current system date. onclick of button.  I need to add nine bussiness days to current day and display it into input value,
so that only weekdays are exclude when we add the days.
For example, 
 if you have today's date (01/31/2011) and i want to add 9 days, the 
 answer should be 10/3/06 because the(02/03/2011) weekend should not be counted.
 Does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: Will holidays (e.g. Christmas or Easter) also be excluded? If yes, you will need to get that data from some online source or provide it yourself...

Answer (score 0):

for this you need to crate one sql function like:

create function fn_IsWeekDay 
(
    @date datetime 
)
returns bit 
as 
begin

```
declare @dtfirst int
declare @dtweek int 
declare @iswkday bit 

set @dtfirst = @@datefirst - 1
set @dtweek = datepart(weekday, @date) - 1

if (@dtfirst + @dtweek) % 7 not in (5, 6)
    set @iswkday = 1 --business day
else
    set @iswkday = 0 --weekend

return @iswkday
```

end

Short and sweet. Now you can simply do this:

if dbo.fn_IsWeekDay(@date) = 1 
begin 
    --do some magic here ;
end

--or

implemented functionality

Answer (score 0):

You probably will need something more advanced, but assuming that you just want to discard Saturday and Sunday you can do something like this (just basic calculation, hope I did not count wrong):

```
<script>
today = new Date();
endDate=today; //Init.

alert(today);

dayOfWeek=today.getDay();

//0: Sunday
if(dayOfWeek==0 || dayOfWeek==1)endDate.setDate(today.getDate() + 11);
else if(dayOfWeek==6)endDate.setDate(today.getDate() + 12);
else endDate.setDate(today.getDate() + 13);

alert(endDate);
</script>
```

EDIT: this assumes "woking days" Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri

Comment: The working principle is quite easy. dayOfWeek is an integer in the range 0-6 telling you which day it is today (0 = Sunday). If it's Sunday or Monday, you have to add 11 full days to have 9 working days, if its Saturday you need to add 12 days otherwise you need to add 13 days. If you take a paper and try to figure out why, you will understand it right away

Comment: if i want to display in this format 04-Feb-2011 wat i need to do, why it is showing like this Wed Feb 9 14:51:00 UTC+0530 2011 what is utc+0530

Comment: UTC+05:30 refers to your local time http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%2B05:30. You can format the date as you like the methods of the endDate object. You can learn here: http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/10_ways_to_format_time_and_date_using_javascript.php3

Comment: sorry but am not able change the format can u please help me to come out of this i need this format

Comment: I suggest you to have a look at how these things work. alert(endDate.getDay()+"/"+endDate.getMonth()+"/"+endDate.getFullYear());

Comment: It is probably the contrary, it is showing a number too little, since the array probably starts from 0 for January instead than 1. Just add +1 to the month. alert(endDate.getDay()+"/"+(endDate.getMonth()+1)+"/"+endDate.getFullYear());

Comment: @Danilo endDate.getday() is taking recent day because it is stored in array and it will check if it is next week friday date it will replace it with this week date,

Comment: @Danilo it is solved ie instead of getdate() we have used getday(); thanks a lot for u r valuable responses